# Issues setting up GridDB web API

Tags: python, postman, griddb

I'm a beignner in GridDB and trying to setup GridDB web API. I am following this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-pw93P-lm0&list=PLZiizI6Euect9q64akYBkiqLMS78UTwjO&index=18

The problem is when I'm trying to spin up the container using postman I get this error:

```
{
    "version": "v2",
    "errorCode": 145028,
    "errorMessage": "[145028:JC_BAD_CONNECTION] Failover timed out (trialCount=5, failureMillis=5154, timeoutMillis=5000, reason=[145028:JC_BAD_CONNECTION] Failed to connect (address=/hostaddress, reason=Connection refused (Connection refused)), history(trial, millisFromInitial, millisFromPrev, reason)=[(1, 0, 0, [145028:JC_BAD_CONNECTION] Failed to connect (address=/hostaddress, reason=Connection refused (Connection refused))), (2, 69, 69, [145028:JC_BAD_CONNECTION] Failed to connect (address=/hostaddress, reason=Connection refused (Connection refused))), (3, 1109, 1040, [145028:JC_BAD_CONNECTION] Failed to connect (address=/hostaddress, reason=Connection refused (Connection refused))), (4, 2156, 1047, [145028:JC_BAD_CONNECTION] Failed to connect (address=/hostaddress, reason=Connection refused (Connection refused))), (5, 3195, 1039, [145028:JC_BAD_CONNECTION] Failed to connect (address=/hostaddress, reason=Connection refused (Connection refused))), (6, 4215, 1020, [145028:JC_BAD_CONNECTION] Failed to connect (address=/***, reason=Connection refused (Connection refused)))])"
}
```

The postman request is `http://[host]:8080/griddb/v2/myCluster/dbs/public/containers`
I'm using default username and pass and the body type is set to raw/json.

I have revisited all of my config files and everything is updated as per video tutorial. Can someone tell me what I am missing?